# How does the derived class objects look like in memory?

Tags: c#, oop, c#-4.0, inheritance

I am still a little confused..
I asked a question few days back that if derived class instances refers to its base classes .. i got an answer that "NO, it does not, derived classes just inherits and contain all the members of base ... **if this is so, then how are the derived class objects saved in memory??**

does the address of derived class object gives any info. about its base class?

Comment: I think the answer to [C# - How does CLR organize memory/reference during the inheritance?][1] answers your question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385990/c-sharp-how-does-clr-organize-memory-reference-during-the-inheritance

Answer (score 4):

Here is the [article](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/09/internals-of-net-objects-and-use-of-sos.html) which shows object memory representation. Fields of base and derived classses are stored together. And methods are put into Method Table Structure

Answer (score 2):

How it is actually (physically) layed-out is an 'implementation detail'. The framework (CLR) may specify this to some detail, the language does not do so at all.

But you can imagine it looks like `[[base class members][derived class members]]`

And a reference to an instance would just point to the beginning address of the base class.

It is the type of the reference (base or derived) that determines which part is 'visible'.