# String is not being assigned?

Tags: c#, variables, inheritance, variable-assignment

```
using System;

public class Shurli
{
    public class MyTest
    {
        private string name = "qwe";   // the name field
        public string Name   // the Name property
        {
            get
            {
                return this.name;
            }
        }
    }

    public class yourJs : MyTest
    {
        private string name = "chah";
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var met = new yourJs();

        string acer = met.Name;
        Console.WriteLine(acer);
    }
}
```

I fully expected the output to be "chah", but the output was "qwe". I've been trying to figure this since a few hours ago but still haven't figured it out. Can someone please help?

Visual studio gives the warning: "The field 'Shurli.yourJs.name' is assigned but its value is never used"

Comment: tried putting a break point ?

Comment: You have added the yourJS.name as private ..

Comment: When met.Name is called, shouldn't `this.name` refer to `met.name`? _met_ is an object which was instantiated from the class _yourJs_, and _yourJs_ contains the code `private string name = "chah";`. So shouldn't _met.name_ evaluate to "chah"?

Comment: @bit `MyTest.name` is also private

Answer (score 4):

The `name` fields in the `MyTest` and `yourJs` classes are in two different scopes - they are completely independent from one another, even though they have the same name.

To make the code work the way you describe, `name` should be declared only in the base class as a `protected` field and then assigned in the child class.

```
public class MyTest
{
    protected string name = "qwe";   // the name field
    public string Name   // the Name property
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}

public class yourJs : MyTest
{
    public yourJs()
    {
        name = "chah";
    }
}
```

Comment: @discussedtree `private` means that the only class that has declared that class has access to it.

Comment: When met.Name is called, shouldn't `this.name` refer to `met.name`? _met_ is an object which was instantiated from the class _yourJs_, and _yourJs_ contains the code `private string name = "chah";`. So shouldn't _met.name_ evaluate to "chah"?

Comment: @discussedtree the object has *two* `name` fields, each with a different value.  The `name` variable in scope for that method has the value that gets printed.  The other (and in your case, inaccessible and unused) field has the other value.

Answer (score 0):

The  `met.Name` will refer to Name the inherited property in MyTest as yourJs contains only `name` which is a private member and could not be access directed form outside the class. Remember that C# is case sensitive and `name` and `Name` are two different variables.

If you want to access the yourJs name private data member then you need to make it public or access its values to some public method/property.

Just to check if you can access the Member `name` in `yourJs` we make it public.

```
public class yourJs : MyTest
{
    public string name = "chah";
}

static void Main()
{
    var met = new yourJs();

    string acer = met.name;
    Console.WriteLine(acer);
}
```

**Edit** based on comments, about the relation between private members and public properties.

[Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

> A property is a member that provides a flexible mechanism to read,
>   write, or compute the value of a private field. Properties can be used
>   as if they are public data members, but they are actually special
>   methods called accessors. This enables data to be accessed easily and
>   still helps promote the safety and flexibility of methods.

Comment: So why does met.Name refer to MyTest.name? MyTest.name is also private

Comment: met.Name is a public property and could be accessed from outside the class. As this public property is part of your class MyTest so it can access the private member of MyTest i.e. name, this will help you understanding this, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

Comment: When met.Name is called, shouldn't this.name refer to met.name?

Comment: met is the object you are referring, so this refers to met. If you change return this.name; to return name; you will get the same result.

Comment: _met_ is an object which was instantiated from the class _yourJs_, and _yourJs_ contains the code `private string name = "chah";`. So shouldn't _met.name_ evaluate to "chah"?

Comment: The class yourJs inherits MyTest that makes Name available in yourJs so met.Name refers to yourJs.Name

Comment: In `yourJs`, `name` is defined as "chah", so shouldn't `met.name` evaluate to "chah"?

Comment: You are not access name of yourJs but Name of MyTest through yourJs

Comment: But why? I was calling the `MyTest`method of `met.name`, which is instantiated from the class `yourJs`. Shouldn't it refer to the MyTest method of `yourJs`?

Comment: I think you need to debug and try to understand the execution flow, http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Answer (score 0):

`private string name = "chah";` will declare a **new** field within the class `yourJs`.
Therefore you have **two** fields called `name` - one in `MyTest` and one on `yourJs`.

AND: The property `Name` returns the field `MyTest.name`, because `Name` is declared in `MyTest`.

This has nothing to do with the `private` modifier - the problem is the introduction of a second `name` field.

If you want to change the value of `name` in `yourJs`, you have to declare it different:

```
public class MyTest {
    protected string name = "qwe";   // This is the ONLY name field, visible by inherited classes

    public string Name {
        get { return this.name; }
    }
}

public class yourJs: MyTest {
    public yourJs() {
        name = "chah";              // Change the value of MyTest.name
        base.name = "chah";         // Same as above, but explicit useage of base class MyTest
    }
}
```

Comment: When met.Name is called, shouldn't `this.name` refer to `met.name`? _met_ is an object which was instantiated from the class _yourJs_, and _yourJs_ contains the code `private string name = "chah";`. So shouldn't _met.name_ evaluate to "chah"?

Comment: No, because the scope of `this` is the property getter of `MyTest`. So `this.name` refers to the field of `MyTest`. And, everything in `MyTest` doesn't know anything of `yourJs`.

Comment: `MyTest` is inherited by `yourJs`

Comment: Exactly. I think this is confusing for you, because you gave both fields the same name `name`. You can easily rename the field `yourJs.name` to `yourJs.name2` for example - and there will be no difference in your running code.

Comment: "AND: The property Name returns the field MyTest.name" - but why? I was calling the `MyTest`method of `met.name`, which is instantiated from the class `yourJs`. Shouldn't it refer to the `MyTest` method of `yourJs`?

Answer (score 0):

In memory a `yourJs` object would have one `Name` property and two instance fields named `name` (one inherited from its *base class* `MyTest` and one declared in the *derived class* itself).

- The field `name` declared in the derived type **hides** the inherited field.
- The inherited property `Name` will *always* reference the *inherited field* `name` no matter what access modifier you use for the fields.

You have three options to get the desired output:

**Option 1**: As mentioned by BJ Myers, the `name` field should be declared only in the base class and then assigned in the derived class.

**Option 2**: Declare a new property with the same name in the derived class (hiding the inherited property).

```
public class MyTest
{
    private string name = "qwe";
    public string Name { get { return name; } }
}

public class yourJs : MyTest
{
    private string name = "chah";
    public new string Name { get { return name; } }
}
```

**Option 3**: Override the inherited property to use the field declared in the derived class.

```
public class MyTest
{
    private string name = "qwe";
    public virtual string Name { get { return name; } }
}

public class yourJs : MyTest
{
    private string name = "chah";
    public override string Name { get { return name; } }
}
```

Comment: "The inherited property Name will always reference the inherited field name no matter what access modifier you use for the fields." Why? Is it because the inherited field has scope precedence over the newly defined field?

Comment: This is how the CLR handles member inheritance and it totally makes sense, you wouldn't want an inherited _function member_ to produce different results in a derived class, unless you explicitly override it. Have a look at this question: [How does CLR organize memory/reference during the inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1385990/3052062)